# Allow users to customize app colors?

Tags: android, resources, styles

I want to let users customize various colors of my app. My app palette consists of three colors, I have implemented a color picker so users can choose each of these color values.

My problem is that I don't know how to define which views use the colors. e.g: give a view customColor1 as background and customColor2 as text color on it's layout, nor how to apply the custom color to it.

---

My initial idea was to a color resource for each color on the palette so I could set the default values and also apply them to views e.g: `android:background="@color/customColor1"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="customColor1">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="customColor2">#7A7A7A</color>
    <color name="customColor3">#0044AA</color>
</resources>
```

Would it be possible to replace occurrences of @color/customColor1 with it's custom value? if not, how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change that. 
Instead you can store the values of the colors to be used in `SharedPreferences` and every time your app launches you can access these colors and use it any way you like it.

Comment: I'm already storing the values in shared preferences, but I don't know how to define which views use the colors. e.g: give a view customColor1 as background and customColor2 as text color. nor how to apply the the colors to them.

Comment: You can set the colors programmatically as soon as you get the color from the `SharedPreferences`. But what you want is completely impossible

Comment: I understand. How can I set them once I got the color from shared preferences? What I don't understand is how to write the layout so that I can tell which elements are to be applied the custom color

Comment: So I think what your problem is, is that the user can choose one color for text and one color for background. So it's simple. Store the color options as colors itself in values.xml. While storing the color preferences in the `SharedPreferences` use one key `colorText` and store the id of the text color in it and other key `colorBckg` and store the id of the background color in it and then call TextView.setTextColor(`//what you got in colorText`) and then also set the background of the activity using what you got in `colorBckg`

Comment: I understand, but that would work only if I limited the users to a set of predetermined colors however I'm using a color picker to let them choose any color they want. Still I could do what you suggested and simply setTextColor and setBackgroundColor, the problem is that sometimes customColor1 is used for text, sometimes for background and sometimes for borders. Do you know what I mean? So I need to use a combination of xml to specify what customColor is used where and programming to customize the customColor

Comment: Ok. At last I got it. Unfortunately I am not capable of answering that :(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of a resource at runtime.

I recommend storing the color in a `SharedPreference` or with some other form of local storage so that you can persist the value and access it again wherever you need it.

Comment: I will store the value in shared preferences. My question wasn't clear. I care about what I want to do, not about how to do it. I thought using resources would be a good idea to store the default values and so I could set it to views with `android:background="@color/customColor1"` but I'm not tied to the idea. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can not. `Resources` are bundled at compile time in the apk

Comment: I clarified the question since it was confusing, changing resources was just my idea on how to do it.